# Why are the Flutter guide lines broken in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Why are the guidelines for Flutter broken up into pieces (as shown on the screenshot) in VS Code. This feature comes from the official Flutter extension for VS Code. Is there a fix for that? I have tried switching all the settings off and on, uninstalling the Flutter plugin.

[image]

Comment: You want them to be gone or do you want them to be a solid line?

Comment: I want them to be a solid line

Comment: Did you check with other VSCode themes? Maybe they are being styled by your theme.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the default Visual Studio theme and Material Theme extension. None worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VS Code, if you head to File->Preferences->Settings, search for 'previewFlutter'. That should give you the `Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides` option. Make sure to uncheck that and that should remove those lines after saving and restarting VS Code!

Edit:

Considering you want the lines but want them to be solid, heading to File->Preferences->Settings and setting `Editor: Line Height` to 17 makes them solid. That is the sweet spot on my editor, but it depends on your font-size (mine is 14). Make sure that `Dart: Preview Ui Guides` is checked!

Comment: I want the lines to combine into a solid line, not remove them.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case then I believe it's a matter of the editor's line height. On my editor, changing the line height to 17 removes the space between the guidelines and makes it solid. 17 seems to be the sweet spot, but you might need to tweak it a bit. Hope it helps!

Comment: heyo! who knew font line height would mess with indentGuides! nice catch! Also, you can set `"editor.lineHeight" = 0` to let VSCode adjust the line height itself based on the font size. Don't have to keep changing both font and lineheight every time.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#ffffffa2",
        "editorIndentGuide.background": "#efefef70",
    },
    // most probably these are responsible
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": false,
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": false
}
```

Here are some setting which you can add to your settings.json which can help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this option, too. If I changed line hight all the code became too densed and I didn't like the way it looked.

So, finally, as I was searching for a better font for my editor I suddenly realized Fira Code solved this issue!

Just put FiraCode-Regular into Preferences -> Settings -> Editor: Font Family and you'll be good to go. I hope so.

[Screenshot of solid guide lines in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbGg5.png)