# My vscode bracket pair and flutter guidelines are separated. How can i fix?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently enabled preview flutter ui guides, but my vscode bracket pairs and guidelines are separated.
How can i fix this ?

[image]

I want like this

[image]

Comment: Which one you want? Disable other one.

Comment: I Want both just like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eO7C.png

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62379481/12215054

Comment: Yes, I try still same

Comment: I don't see bracket pair lines in your comment image

Answer (score 2):

This overlap happens from Editor>Guides:Indentation, turn this off

[image]

And turn on **Flutter Ui Guides and Preview UI Guides**

[image]

This  will provide only Flutter Ui Guides, you can change color opacity of `Editor>Guides:Indentation` to make similar

My current setUP

```json
{  ...
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": true,
    "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true,
    "editor.guides.indentation": true,
    "editor.lineHeight": 0,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorIndentGuide.background": "#93939332",
        "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#5757575e",
    },
    "dart.previewBazelWorkspaceCustomScripts": false
}
```

And it provides better

[image]